# Lots of BSODs with new SSD on Windows 8.1 x64 Pro

Tags: windows-8.1, ssd, bsod

I bought a Samsung 850 EVO 120GB SSD about a month ago. I installed Windows 8.1 x64 Pro on it, and since then my PC is almost useless because I get all sorts of BSODs (currently at 20) which weren't present with an HDD.

Specs:

- mobo: ASRock P55 pro (2.60 BIOS)
- CPU: Intel i5-650 (@BCLK 160 because of the RAMs)
- GPU: VTX3D HD6790 1GB
- RAM: Kingston HyperX Blue DDR3 1600 2x8GB
- HDD: Western Digital Caviar Green 2TB
- SSD: Samsung 850 EVO 120GB
- DVD: Asus SATA DVD-RW
- Tenda W322P+ PCI Wi-Fi adapter

The drive controller is set AHCI with Hot-Plug but I tried IDE with Enhanced setting but didn't made any difference.
The VGA uses the latest AMD 14.12 Omega driver and the on board audio is using the latest hd audio driver from Realtek anything else is from Microsoft.

As you see there is an Overclock on the CPU but I tried with default clock and I still got BSODs.

I checked the temperatures, but everything is OK. CPU after 1 hour stress test was about 60° C. The VGA after 1 hour stress test was 75° C.

I run HHD sentinel tests on the WD HDD but that returned OK, the Samsung Magician shows that the SSD is Good and is using the latest firmware.

Today I got a BSOD while working and after reboot I got immediately a Critical Process Died BSOD. When I tried to set Windows back to an earlier date it told me that that the system protection must be enabled, but it was enabled for ALL partitions. I was able to set it back with a few tricks, but this is still annoying.

[Here are my BSODs in a ZIP](http://1drv.ms/1KdgE4x)

I tried to post my problem on the MS forum but the only answer I got was to uninstall Avast because one of the BSOD was connected to Avast. Anyway I tried uninstalling Avast, but it didn't made any difference.

Is there anything I can try to get rid of these BSODs?

A few of the BSODs are from the AMD VGA driver, so I installed the latest beta diver, but still I'm getting BSODs, but since then I'm not getting any VGA driver related BSODs.

[here are the BSODs](http://1drv.ms/1bvacKk) since I changed the VGA driver.

Comment: There are a few possible causes: 1) Not SSD related at all (which means the error would go away if you test or run a while with a HDD). 2) IO related (either problems with the SSD, the drivers, the chipset or the SATA cable). Quicket to test that with: Change cable and or try a different SATA port.

Comment: We only need the .dmp files for the most recent crashes, after you solved the problems with your display driver and Avast.  You say it made no difference but are you still getting BSOD indicating its caused by Avast.

Comment: The latest I'we checkd with the windbg showed Unable to verify timestamp for aswSP.sys but in analyse-v shows the process as csrss.exe so I don't know if its Avast related or not.

Comment: csrss.exe has nothing to do with Avast.  My research indicates that aswSP.sys is the avast! self protection module which means you still are loading a Avast kernel level driver.  So use Auotruns and configure your system NOT to load it.  Simply keeping Avast and the OS updated would solve this problem more then likely.

Comment: [Avast Uninstall Utilty](http://www.avast.com/en-gb/uninstall-utility)

Comment: Thanks, I run the utility in safe mode, and cahnged my sata cable to a brand new one and changed the connection from sata0 to sata4 on the MB, now we will see if any of this helps. Oh I just saw you edited your comment, My system is up to date and I also kept Avast up to date.

Comment: So it turns out that nothing is changed today I got a KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED BSOD according to Windbg its probably caused by `hardware ( nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::'string'+3aa31 )`